# Text overlap detection with weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to detect when a `div.text` is on top of another (within the parent `div#element`), the background of the parent should change depending the existance of the overlap.

The issue is that when there's no overlap the script still detects one, this may be caused because each `.text` compares their position with itself over again.

```js
$(".text").each(function() {
  var self_text = $(this),
    self_textid = self_text.attr('id'),
    self_textLeft = self_text.position().left,
    self_textTop = self_text.position().top,
    self_textWidth = self_text.width(),
    self_textHeight = self_text.height();

  $(".text").each(function() {
    var self_shape = $(this),
      self_shapeLeft = self_shape.position().left,
      self_shapeTop = self_shape.position().top,
      self_shapeWidth = self_shape.width(),
      self_shapeHeight = self_shape.height();

    // check if .text overlaps
    if (
      (self_textLeft + self_textWidth) > self_shapeLeft &&
      self_textLeft < (self_shapeLeft + self_shapeWidth) &&
      (self_textTop + self_textHeight) > self_shapeTop &&
      self_textTop < (self_shapeTop + self_shapeHeight)
    ) {
      // overlap
      $('#elements').css('background', 'red');
    } else {
      // no overlap
      $('#elements').css('background', 'green')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#elements,
.text {
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#elements {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div class="text" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;">text1</div>
  <div class="text" style="left: 100px; top: 50px;">text2</div>
  <div class="text" style="left: 10px; top: 200px;">text3</div>
  <div class="text" style="left: 10px; top: 45px;">text4</div>
</div>
```

How can I tell the script to ignore itself whenever it loops again without changing the `.text` class, also is there any way that code could be improved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you include the div itself to check against, try adding it to a not:

```js
var $textDivs = $(".text"); // cache this so you are not performing the lookup every time in your loop
$textDivs.each(function() {
  var self_text = $(this),
    self_textid = this.id,
    self_textLeft = self_text.position().left,
    self_textTop = self_text.position().top,
    self_textWidth = self_text.width(),
    self_textHeight = self_text.height(),
    hasNotMatched = true;

  $textDivs.not(self_text).each(function() { // added to a not so not checked against itself
    var self_shape = $(this),
      self_shapeLeft = self_shape.position().left,
      self_shapeTop = self_shape.position().top,
      self_shapeWidth = self_shape.width(),
      self_shapeHeight = self_shape.height();

    // check if .text overlaps
    if (
      (self_textLeft + self_textWidth) > self_shapeLeft &&
      self_textLeft < (self_shapeLeft + self_shapeWidth) &&
      (self_textTop + self_textHeight) > self_shapeTop &&
      self_textTop < (self_shapeTop + self_shapeHeight)
    ) {
      // overlap
      $('#elements').css('background', 'red');
      hasNotMatched = false;

      return false; // break out of each loop so as no need to process anymore and so overlap doesn't turn back green
    } else {
      // no overlap
      $('#elements').css('background', 'green')
    }
  });
  
  return hasNotMatched;    // this will break out of outer loop if matched on inner loop
});
```

```css
#elements,
.text {
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#elements {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div class="text" style="left:20px; top:20px;">text1</div>
  <div class="text" style="left:100px; top:50px;">text2</div>
  <div class="text" style="left:90px; top:40px;">text3</div>
  <div class="text" style="left:190px; top:30px;">text4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The background still stays green with an overlap : https://jsfiddle.net/brwzf44w/2/ is there any another issue that I didn't thought of ?

Comment: @Lidow, edited above answer - you need to break out of the loop when you get an overlapping element otherwise you will go back to green if you carry on and another element doesn't overlap.  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brwzf44w/4/

Comment: Still, if the .text is after another it will not work with it, see : https://jsfiddle.net/brwzf44w/6/

Comment: Ok see above edit, you also need to break out of outer loop too

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the current element with

```
$(".text").not($(this))
```

There's also an issue with the logic of your solution - if the last elements checked don't overlap it will change the background to green. One way to handle this is to set the background to green as the default. And if an overlap is detected change the background to red.

There are a few more optimizations that could be made here - like once an overlap has been detected it could exit.

Like this:

```js
$(".text").each(function() {
  $('#elements').css('background', 'green');

  var self_text = $(this),
    self_textid = self_text.attr('id'),
    self_textPosition = self_text.position(),
    self_textLeft = self_textPosition.left,
    self_textTop = self_textPosition.top,
    self_textWidth = self_text.width(),
    self_textHeight = self_text.height();

  $(".text").not($(this)).each(function() {
    var self_shape = $(this),
      self_shapePosition = self_shape.position(),
      self_shapeLeft = self_shapePosition.left,
      self_shapeTop = self_shapePosition.top,
      self_shapeWidth = self_shape.width(),
      self_shapeHeight = self_shape.height();

    // check if .text overlaps
    if (
      (self_textLeft + self_textWidth) > self_shapeLeft &&
      self_textLeft < (self_shapeLeft + self_shapeWidth) &&
      (self_textTop + self_textHeight) > self_shapeTop &&
      self_textTop < (self_shapeTop + self_shapeHeight)
    ) {
      // overlap
      $('#elements').css('background', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#elements,
.text {
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#elements {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div class="text" style="left: 20px; top: 20px;">text1</div>
  <div class="text" style="left: 100px; top: 50px;">text2</div>
  <div class="text" style="left: 10px; top: 200px;">text3</div>
  <div class="text" style="left: 10px; top: 45px;">text4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The background still stays green with an overlap : jsfiddle.net/brwzf44w/2 is there any another issue that I didn't thought of ?

Comment: Yes, there's an error in the logic. I've updated the solution.

Comment: Still, if the .text is after another it will not work with it, see : jsfiddle.net/brwzf44w/7

Comment: Yes, there's still an issue in your logic. You're not checking all the overlapping conditions. But we can't do ALL the work for you ;)

Comment: Indeed, I'm just trying to understand the logic :)